# Google Map API adding more then 10 markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add bulk markers on google map using following code.

```
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var bounds = null;
var gdir;

var properties_address = new Array();
var blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
blueIcon.iconSize = new GSize(26, 33);
markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };
blueIcon.image = "https://mysite/images/marker.gif";

properties_address = ["Abohar,Punjab,india", "Achhalda,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Achhnera,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Adari,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Adilabad,Andhra Pradesh,india", "Adipur,Gujarat,india", "Adoni,Andhra Pradesh,india", "Adoor,Kerala,india", "Agartala,Tripura,india", "Agra,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Ahmedabad,Gujarat,india", "Ahmedgarh,Punjab,india", "Ahmednagar,Maharashtra,india", "Aizawl,Mizoram,india", "Ajmer,Rajasthan,india", "Akaltara,Chhattisgarh,india", "Akola,Maharashtra,india", "Alappuzha,Kerala,india"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    bounds = new GLatLngBounds;
    initialize();
 });

 function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(21.88, 78.442626), 5);
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

        $.each(properties_address, function(index, property) {
          showAddressByAddress(index, property, false);
        });                        
    }
}

function showAddressByAddress(index,address, is_custom)
{
    if(address){
        geocoder.getLatLng(address,function(point) {
            var marker = new GMarker(point,markerOptions);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
            bounds.extend(marker.getPoint());
            map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
            map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());

            GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
                if(!is_custom){
                    address_html = address + '<br /><a id="route_'+index+'" href="#" class="route_url" data-address="'+ address +'">Route from here</a>';
                }else{
                    address_html = address;
                }

                marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address_html);
            });               

        });
    }
}
```

The code is working fine until I provide it 10 addresses in properties_address array, but more then 10 address its giving me following error.

```
a is null
http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_ALL/mapfiles/377a/maps2.api/main.js
Line 1131
```

Comment: Is the sample code above main.js? Where is `a`?

Comment: 'a is null' is a typical error you'll get from Google Maps javascript when there's a JS error in your own code.

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the 11th array item?

Comment: You should think about moving to version 3 of the Maps API, this is version 2 code. http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/basics.html

Comment: ["Abohar,Punjab,india", "Achhalda,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Achhnera,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Adari,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Adilabad,Andhra Pradesh,india", "Adipur,Gujarat,india", "Adoni,Andhra Pradesh,india", "Adoor,Kerala,india", "Agartala,Tripura,india", "Agra,Uttar Pradesh,india", "Ahmedabad,Gujarat,india", "Ahmedgarh,Punjab,india", "Ahmednagar,Maharashtra,india", "Aizawl,Mizoram,india", "Ajmer,Rajasthan,india", "Akaltara,Chhattisgarh,india", "Akola,Maharashtra,india", "Alappuzha,Kerala,india"]

Comment: @omarello There is no main.js. My javascript is with in the page. I think google map returning its javascript in main.js

Comment: @duncan : I checked my code and if I provide any 10 addresses from the array that I had commented above, then its working fine, but more then that its returning me 'a is null' error.

Comment: Where are properties_address,markerOptions and bounds defined? You might want to add that code to your question too.

Comment: @duncan - Thanks for reply, question code updated, in this code i had also included jQuery in header files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Fixed, I just skipped the point which is not found by geocode.

```
function showAddressByAddress(index,address, is_custom)
{
    if(address){
        geocoder.getLatLng(address,function(point) {
            if(point){
                var marker = new GMarker(point,markerOptions);

                map.addOverlay(marker);
                bounds.extend(marker.getPoint());
                map.setZoom(map.getBoundsZoomLevel(bounds));
                map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());


                GEvent.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
                    if(!is_custom){
                        address_html = address + '<br /><a id="route_'+index+'" href="#" class="route_url" data-address="'+ address +'">Route from here</a>';
                    }else{
                        address_html = address;
                    }

                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml(address_html);
                });

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using firebug to view the properties of the array sounds like one of the items inside of it is null.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myCars=["Saab","Volvo","BMW"];;
console.log(myCars);    
</script>
</html>`
```

then look in the firebug console window to view properties of the array
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Array name is wrong:

```
var properties_add21ress = new Array();
```

Comment: its just spelling mistake when posting question, but that was not the issue. Thanks for the reply.